# Calling trait static method from another static method (rust)

Tags: static, rust, traits

Can you call a trait static method implemented by types from another trait static method implemented in the trait?  For example:

```
trait SqlTable {
  fn table_name() -> String;

  fn load(id: i32) -> Something {
    ...
    Self::table_name()    // <-- this is not right
    ...
  }
}
```

This is now working thanks to Chris and Arjan (see comments/answers below)

```
fn main() {
  let kiwibank = SqlTable::get_description(15,None::<Account>);
}

trait SqlTable {
    fn table_name(_: Option<Self>) -> String;

    fn get_description(id: i32, _: Option<Self>) -> String {
        println!("Fetching from {} table", SqlTable::table_name(None::<Self>) );
        String::from_str("dummy result")
    }
}

struct Account {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}
impl SqlTable for Account {
    fn table_name(_: Option<Account>) -> String { String::from_str("account") }
}
```

Comment: Where there is no `Self` or `self` in the function signature, it is not callable at present. The standard workaround until UFCS comes is to take an argument `_: Option<Self>` and pass it `None::<T>`.

Comment: Thanks that workaround gets me closer and solves the call in main().  But it doesn't address the argument in println!() which cannot determine a type.  Edits forthcoming above.  I'm starting to think the answer to the original question is simply "no" and I need to rethink the paradigm.

Comment: `table_name` is still not callable as it has no connection with the `Self` type. But you are right—rethinking the paradigm is probably a good idea.

Comment: Hey I think I just got it working! thanks, updating above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes, you can call a trait static method [implemented by types] from another trait static method [implemented in the trait].
- Static methods are always called on a trait like `SomeTrait::some_method()`.
- Where there is no Self or self in [a trait] function signature, it is not callable at present. The standard workaround until UFCS comes is to take an argument `_: Option<Self>` and pass it `None::<T>`.

See original question for code that (as of today) compiles.

Comment: Clever workaround. By the looks of it [UFCS](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ufcs.html) has since been implemented, I think `<Account as SqlTable>::get_description(15)` would work now.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change Self to SqlTable:

```
trait SqlTable {
  fn table_name() -> String;

  fn load(id: i32) -> Self {
    ...
    SqlTable::table_name()    // <-- this is not right
    ...
  }
}
```

Static methods are always called on a trait like SomeTrait::some_method(). Bug [#6894](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6894) covers this issue.

Comment: Thanks that got me closer but I still have no compilable simple example of this form.

Comment: Note that the compiler needs a way to work out what the `Self` type is, that is, which `impl` is being called (see the updated question for the work-around that's idiomatic until [UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/132) lands).

Answer (score 1):

This works without any workarounds with current Rust (verified with 1.65.0):

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn x() -> i32 {
        1
    }
}

struct Struct {
    y: i32,
}

impl Struct {
    fn new(y: i32) -> Self {
        Self { y }
    }

    fn f(self) -> i32 {
        Self::x() + self.y
    }
}

impl Trait for Struct {}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(Struct::new(1).f(), 2);
}
```