# How to call a trait method without a struct instance?

Tags: rust

If I have a struct with a method that doesn't have `self` as an argument, I can call the method via `SomeStruct::method()`. I can't seem to do the same with a method that's defined from a trait. For example:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn one_trait() -> uint;
}

struct SomeStruct;
impl SomeStruct {
    fn one_notrait() -> uint {
        1u
    }
}
impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
    fn one_trait() -> uint {
        1u
    }
}

#[test]
fn testing() {
    SomeStruct::one_trait();   // doesn't compile
    SomeStruct::one_notrait(); // compiles
}
```

The compiler gives the error "unresolved name 'SomeStruct::one_trait.'"

How can I call a struct's implementation of a trait method directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling trait static method from another static method (rust)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541074/calling-trait-static-method-from-another-static-method-rust)

Comment: (It’s not a *precise* duplicate, but it certainly covers the same ground, and the answer that you simply can’t do this without workarounds until UFCS comes is true.)

Comment: What is the error message for the "doesn't compile" variable? (It's good to include the precise compiler output, so that everyone is on exactly the same page. :) )

Comment: Of course. I'll edit the question to add the compiler error.

Comment: Chris's answer still holds. Not callable at present (until UFCS lands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is currently not possible. The problem is that you cannot explicitly specify the `Self` type. But there is an active [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/active/0046-ufcs.md) in the pipeline which should allow this when implemented.

In the meantime, you could work around it like this:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn one_trait(&self) -> uint;
}

struct Static<T>;

struct SomeStruct;

impl SomeTrait for Static<SomeStruct> {
    fn one_trait(&self) -> uint { 1 }
}

fn main() {
    let type_to_uint = Static::<SomeStruct>.one_trait();
    println!("{}", type_to_uint);
}
```

This is how I map a type to an integer (if that's what you're after). It's done without having a value of type `T`. The dummy value, `Static<T>`, has a size of zero.

Comment: @PureW: The RFC has been rejected, and thus the file removed :x

Answer (score 12):

```rust
trait Animal {
    fn baby_name() -> String;
}

struct Dog;

impl Dog {
    fn baby_name() -> String {
        String::from("Spot")
    }
}

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn baby_name() -> String {
        String::from("puppy")
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("A baby dog is called a {}", <Dog as Animal>::baby_name());
}
```

From [Advanced Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name)