# Is it possible to use a trait as syntax sugar for a free function?

Tags: rust

I want to call function depending on external data,
like this:

```
struct Foo {
    data: &'static str,
    handler: Option<fn (i32) -> String>,
}

fn aaa_converter(_: i32) -> String { unimplemented!(); }
fn bbb_converter(_: i32) -> String { unimplemented!(); }

fn main() {
    let _ = Foo{data: "aaa", handler: Some(aaa_converter)};
    let _ = Foo{data: "bbb", handler: Some(bbb_converter)};
    let _ = Foo{data: "ccc", handler: None};
}
```

I have as input the string "aaa", and I need to call `aaa_converter`. All works fine, I put `Foo` objects into the hash map and call proper `handler` if not `None`.

Now I have many such converters and I want to help from the language to deal with them.

Ideally, there would be syntax like this:

```
trait Handler {
    fn handle(a: i32) -> String;
}

impl Handler for "aaa" {
    // ...
}
```

The best match that I can have is:

```
trait Handler {
    fn handle(/*&self, */a: i32) -> String;
}

struct aaa;

impl Handler for aaa {
    fn handle(/*&self, */a: i32) -> String {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

struct Foo {
    data: &'static str,
    handler: &'static Handler,
}

fn main() {}
```

But such code does not compile:

```
the trait `Handler` cannot be made into an object
   = note: method `handle` has no receiver
```

[How to call a trait method without a struct instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355139/how-to-call-a-trait-method-without-a-struct-instance) looks related, but the RFC linked in the answer is out of date. It's also possible something changed since then in the language?

Is it possible to use a trait as a simple pointer to a free function?

Or is there another way to organize handlers?

Comment: *Why*? Why not just have an empty struct, take the `self` parameter, and not use it?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Why use a trait to start with? ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM. my spidey-sense tells me that sometimes they are going to want state. For example, `Foo` is probably the actual handler and `data` should be accessed through `self`.

Comment: @Shepmaster  No, I not need state. I just need syntax like `impl Handler for X`, because of it make clear what function from >20 functions belong to which variant.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `Why use a trait to start with?`, because of `trait` have clear syntax describing which interface I implement to which thing, I have > 20 such functions, and to simplify finding of such functions I need such or similar syntax.

Comment: @Shepmaster >Why? Why not just have an empty struct, take the self parameter, and not use it?  Because of I want ideal solution, and useless 64 bit pointer is not great.

Comment: @user1244932 why do you think the optimizer won't remove the pointer? Why are you micro-optimizing stuff like this **without measuring**?

Comment: @Shepmaster: To be fair, the compiler would have a hard-time removing the data pointer, since *one* implementation of `Handler` could perfectly actually *use* the data pointer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. wouldn't monomorphization deal with that?

Comment: @Shepmaster: `&Handler` is an object trait; monomorphization could avoid allocating an object (using 1 as the data pointer), but it would still take 64-bits.

Comment: @user1244932: Your question is far from clear. From your comments it would appear that you want `Handler` to have **multiple** associated functions; if that's the case it should be reflected in the question! (When you said many converters, I assumed an instance of `Foo` would have a single converter/function since `Handler` has a single function and you would have multiple instances of `Foo`)

Comment: @MatthieuM. that's why I'd change it to `Foo<H: Handler> { handler: H, /* ... */ }` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding here:

1. Rust has functions
2. Rust has "functors"
3. Rust has traits

A function is just that:

```
fn i_am_a_function(a: i32) -> String { a.to_string() }
```

A functor is a function object, that is a function associated to some state. Rust actually has 3 of them:

```
FnOnce(i32) -> String
FnMut(i32) -> String
Fn(i32) -> String
```

And finally Rust has traits:

```
trait Handler {
    fn non_object_safe(a: i32) -> String;
    fn object_safe(&self, a: i32) -> String;
}
```

Traits can be used in two situations:

- to provide bounds in generic functions
- **when object safe**, to provide type erasure

Roughly speaking, a trait is not object safe if any of its associated functions:

- does not have a `&self` or `&mut self` parameter
- mentions `Self` (the type)

For more information on either concept, check the Rust Book.

---

In your situation, you could use:

1. A simple pointer to function: `fn(i32) -> String`
2. A functor `Fn(i32) -> String`
3. An object safe trait

The only thing you cannot use is a non object-safe trait, and of course thanks to Murphy, it's the one option you picked.

In your case, the simplest solution is to use an object safe trait:

```
trait Handler {
    fn handle(&self, a: i32) -> String;
}

struct A;

impl Handler for A {
    fn handle(&self, a: i32) -> String {
        a.to_string()
    }
}

const STATIC_A: &'static Handler = &A;

struct Foo {
    data: &'static str,
    handler: &'static Handler,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { data: "aaa", handler: STATIC_A };
    println!("{}", foo.handler.handle(3));
}
```

If that 64-bits overhead for the data-pointer *really* bother you, then you can use function pointers and build your own virtual table:

```
struct Handler {
    handle: fn(i32) -> String,
}

fn aaa(a: i32) -> String {
    a.to_string()
}

const STATIC_A: &'static Handler = &Handler { handle: aaa };

struct Foo {
    data: &'static str,
    handler: &'static Handler,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { data: "aaa", handler: STATIC_A };
    println!("{}", (foo.handler.handle)(3));
}
```

It's less ergonomic, but it's also 64-bits smaller!

Comment: No, as I pointed in question I already use such code as you show. The problem that I have many such functions as `aaa` and to organize them I need something like traits to simplify finding suitable function in code and show other guys what interface that should implement

Comment: Updated; I'd recommend using trait objects in this case unless you really have a stringent requirement, but just in case I showed how to build a virtual table on your own.