# How do I provide type parameters to trait functions that don't take self?

Tags: rust, type-parameter

This doesn't compile:

```
pub trait TheTrait<T> {
    pub fn without_self() -> T;
    pub fn with_self(&self) -> T {
        TheTrait::without_self()
    }
}
```

because the compiler can't figure out the type parameters for `TheTrait::without_self()`. I want something like `TheTrait<T>::without_self()`, but I can't find a syntax that works. How do I provide the type parameter to `without_self`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling trait static method from another static method (rust)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541074/calling-trait-static-method-from-another-static-method-rust)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Editor's note: This answer is outdated as of Rust 1.0

If there's no `Self` or `self` in the function signature, it's not callable, at least until [UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293) is implemented. For now, you can take `Option<Self>` as an argument, and call with `None::<Self>` as a work-around.

```
pub trait TheTrait<T> {
    fn without_self(Option<Self>) -> T;
    fn with_self(&self) -> T {
        TheTrait::without_self(None::<Self>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want something like `TheTrait<T>::without_self()`, but I can't find a syntax that works. How do I provide the type parameter to `without_self`?

Nowadays, with [Fully Qualified Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) you can do it like this:

```
<T as TheTrait>::without_self()
```